# Numpy doesnt return a value or a simple list but like 30 empty nested lists?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Currently I have an OrderedDict object that looks something like this:

```
OrderedDict([('počivaj', 2), ('v', 2), ('ki', 1), ('šibki', 1), ('še', 1), ('srečno', 1), ('popji', 1), ('le', 1), ('ko', 1), ('let', 1), ('angelj', 1), ('rože', 1), ('mlade', 1), ('mirno', 1), ('ne', 1), ('zibki', 1), ('topli', 1), ('dni', 1), ('cvet', 1), ('šteješ', 1)])
```

I'm using 2 different lists to get out a list of keys and a list of values.

```
first_word_keys = list(words.keys())
first_word_values = list(words.values())


Looks like this:
['v', 'počivaj', 'mlade', 'popji', 'ko', 'mirno', 'še', 'ne', 'topli', 'dni', 'angelj', 'le', 'šibki', 'cvet', 'let', 'šteješ', 'ki', 'rože', 'srečno', 'zibki']
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Now. I'm using Numpy's random choice function to choose a key based on the values of key(weighted random). Since numpy didnt let me use float values I'm using Integers using counter.

```
choiceX = np.random.choice(first_word_keys,first_word_values)
```

What this returns is really kind of remarkable:

```
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[['popji']]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

This is one of the words, hidden in a metric ton of empty nested lists. What did I do to make the numpy.random.choice() return such a weird list instead of just a value? I'm aware there are functions that could remove such a list, but I'm probably not using numpy correctly and would like to fix that before writing extra functions to remove empty nested lists.

Comment: This returned a `numpy` array with shape given by the `first_word_values`.  Those [] represent dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) states, the second parameter of `np.random.choice` is `size`, which stands for the shape of the output, not for the probabilities. You need to provide the `p` parameter, and normalize the probabilities like this:

```
probabilities = np.array(first_word_values).astype(np.float)
probabilities = probabilities / np.sum(probabilities)
choiceX = np.random.choice(first_word_keys, p=probabilities)
```

EDIT: added normalization logic

EDIT: full working code

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np

words = OrderedDict([
  ('počivaj', 2), ('v', 2), ('ki', 1), ('šibki', 1), ('še', 1),
  ('srečno', 1), ('popji', 1), ('le', 1), ('ko', 1), ('let', 1),
  ('angelj', 1), ('rože', 1), ('mlade', 1), ('mirno', 1), ('ne', 1),
  ('zibki',  1), ('topli', 1), ('dni', 1), ('cvet', 1), ('šteješ', 1)
])
first_word_keys = list(words.keys())
first_word_values = list(words.values())

probabilities = np.array(first_word_values).astype(np.float)
probabilities = probabilities / np.sum(probabilities)
choiceX = np.random.choice(first_word_keys, p=probabilities)
print(choiceX)
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. `p` accepts a list of probabilities, not counts. Your answer will likely cause an error out.

Comment: Good catch, let me search for the shortest way to normalize the probabilities

Comment: I have a probability dictionary ready,so switching to that would just take me a few minutes. However I'm smelling a "doesnt sum to one" error. Would your normalization code work for that aswell? Or is it exclusive to a Counter with integer values?

Comment: This code does exactly that: scales the weights so they add up to 1, it doesn't matter if the weights are integers or not. The first line is just some type cast magic to ensure that float division is made instead of integer division at the end.